# top eyelid in rigify

Tags: armature, rigify

I've created a character that I try to rig with rigify. After aligning bones and generating the rig, I noticed that the eyelid control moves bones in a way that makes it impossible to animate closing the eyes. How do I fix this? Weight painting most likely won't do the trick.

Below is an image of upper eyelid, moved top eyelid control (turquoise) and bones that represent eyelid.

[image: Rigify rig when closing an eye lid]

Answer (score 2):

After a little bit of twiddling I found that the problem was bad bone placement. In the metarig that I built for the character, the top eyelid bones were different length and zig-zagging through the top lid. A more careful placement fixed the issue.

For optimal positioning it seems that 4 bones should be roughly equal in length and slightly "inside" the body (if your lid has thickness).

Answer (score 1):

The red controllers are the primary controllers to pose the lid. There are also yellow secondary controllers. For each eye, there is basically one control bone for each deform bone (the green ones). 3 for the top lid, 3 for the bottom lid, and 1 on the left, and 1 on the right.

The primary controllers move the secondary controllers along but you can move them individually for further tweaking.

Just press the "*Face (Secondary)*" Rigify button in the N-panel and you will see them.

When the main controller for the top lid is down then just slide the secondary controllers down a little more to close the lid completely.

[image: example]

Comment: That's a good tactical solution. After digging deeper I found the problem was bone placement in metarig. It was zigzagging in and out of the upper lid and that confused rigify.